# Get Ansible play/task/config level keyword/directives help/reference when in command line. Is it possible?

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for equivalent of ansible-doc  command to help with play/task syntax/keywords.

When I use Ansible from non graphical host, there is a very handy command line tool ansible-doc for help with options/keywords on module level. However if I need to check task level syntax keywords, let's say: I forget how to write loops I have to look it up in Ansible online documentation. (Well, loop is hard to forget but it can be something less common and obvious like serial keyword). Is there command line tool to achieve this? Or maybe way to obtain Ansible online documentation in compact and readable from command line format?

Comment: I don't think so there is any command line tool available for this, but VS Code has an extension that lets you complete the tasks(intellisense)

Comment: @error404, thank you for suggestion, I like vs code and will definitely use this extension when on graphical host. It's a shame they don't have terminal version.

Comment: I wouldn't use words like shame for a fairly good and useful tool like `ansible`. Certainly it will be good to have such kind of cli but that can be requested as feature request to the ansible community

Comment: Ansible is very useful tool, it saved me a lot of time. The purpose of my question was not to understate it, but to learn to use it more conveniently. However based on times this question has been viewed "keyword reference" it's not the feature most people lack, which makes me wonder how do they quickly recall or select needed keyword.

Comment: I understand it was not your intention to understate it. just wanted to tell you to avoid using such words. In case of recall I would say the VS code provides a way to execute the ansible using docker images MS has built so best thing would be to use docker + VS code + ansible + extensions for time being. I understand how much useful is intellisense